# Debugging Node in VS Code (or other IDEs)

Tags: node.js, debugging

In VS code there are two ways to launch the debug console for Node. One is “launch” which executes node and passes in your script. The script executes and node exits which i don’t want to happen. The other way is “attach”, this way you launch node yourself using --inspect then attach VS code to the debugger. Then I have to go to the node console and type “.load myscript”. This will keep the node console open after the script has finished.

What I want is to have ease of use of the “launch” method but keep the node console open at the end like the “attach” approach so I can then type further commands or view the contents of variables. There must be a way to do this but I can’t find out how. Can anyone advise how I could achieve this? I am even happy to only use the “launch” method if I could someone add a breakpoint at the end of code so that it would keep node open.

Comment: Can't you add `debugger;` at the end of your script?

Comment: I can but that won't. I should have been more clear. There's  part on the script about half way through which does around 300 async calls via a loop. So If I add debug at the end it will hit that breakpoint before the async ops finish. I need it 'break' at the end of the last loop. Any thoughts?

Comment: Then if you don't want the process to exit make sure there's an event pending. Simple ways to do this is to listen on a socket (net or http server) or open a database connection. Just add `net.createServer(()=>{}).listen(0)` at the end of your script. Setting port to zero will make the system give you a random available port

Comment: If you are worried that processes may try to connect to your bogus server and clog up your ip tables then you can simply close all incoming connections: `net.createServer(x=>x.end()).listen(0)`

Comment: Awesome that is what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: As I think this may be useful to others as well I'll write it up as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A node.js process will not exit as long as there are events pending. A simple way to do that at the end of your script is to start a server that does nothing:

```
net.createServer(()=>{}).listen(0)
```

Setting the port to `0` will cause the OS to give you a random available port so you don't need to think about what port to use.

This is generally safe if you are on a local network. However, if you are worried about other software connecting to your bogus server you can simply close all incoming connections upon receiving them:

```
net.createServer(x=>x.end()).listen(0)
```